# How to read the VMZ 08 magnetic inductive flow sensor?

Tags: sensor, pulse, counter, flow-sensor

We are in a near-emergency situation where we must read a `VMZ08BS1PEG24CV0` flow sensor. You may see more information including the datasheet [here](https://gms-instruments.com/nl/product/vmz-08-magnetic-inductive-flow-sensor/).

I am being told that we need an NPN/PNP pulse counter to read the output frequency digitally and convert it to flow rate. However, I have no experience with those.
I have Arduinos and Raspberry Pis around, and fairly familiar with programming both in Arduino-C++ and Python. I want to put things together on a breadboard to implement something really fast. I would appreciate it if you could help me know if it is possible and where should I start. Maybe you could be kind to provide me with some examples of relevant circuitry.

Comment: the diagram shows a switch between pin 2 and pin 4 ... connect pin 4 to GND ... connect pin 2 to arduino input ... enable arduino input pullup resistor ... measure the pulses at arduino input ....... before you connect to arduino measure output voltage at pin 4 without any pullup resistor to make sure that it is safe for the arduino

Comment: datasheet says that the output is open collector ... connect it same way as a mechanical switch ... use a pullup resistor

Comment: Some of these devices require the given load and voltage and may not work properly if pulled to only 5 V.

Answer (score 2):

From the diagram on the label you've posted, there appears to be an isolated switch between pins 2 and 4. It's not clear whether it is truly isolated, or a semiconductor switch, so it would be wise to protect against 24 V appearing on it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO07Sz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That protection could either be a zener diode clamp D1, though you might prefer the belt and braces approach of using an opto-iosolator so there's no galvanic connection between the 24 V PSU and your MCU.

Once the pulses are inside the MCU, you can do what you like in software.

If that is a mechanical switch inside the sensor, your software will need to debounce the pulses.

Comment: It surely is not a mechanical switch inside. It is rated as 1000 pulses per liter und max. flow of 25 l/min, so up to 416 Hz. Nevertheless both of your circuits work. I'd suggest using a "fast" coupler with hysteresis and logik level output.